# Using javascript to prevent horizontal scrolling based on screen width

Tags: javascript, screen, horizontal-scrolling, disabled-control

I'm fairly new to Javascript and only use it whenever I need to tweak something a little. However I need to fix the following code:

```
var scrollEventHandler = function()

if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset)
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEventHandler, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
```

Hope anyone is willing to help me out! Thanks!

PS: I'm in a position where I can only work with solutions that I can enter straight into script tags.

Comment: Just a note you can use CSS overflow-x:hidden; on your container element to prevent scrolling as well, you may not need javascript.

Comment: Hi Ryan!

I have disabled the overflow-x, which works flawless on Chrome but Safari still allows you to scroll horizontally even though you won't see the scrollbar. And same goes for mobile.